# Como fazer o Insert de chaves estrangeiras no PHP, para que eu possa ter um controle na hora de Puxar a VIEW

Tags: php, mysql, html5, banco-de-dados

Estou fazendo um projeto, onde os funcionários cadastrados no site (corporativo), possam registrar: Erros e os Clientes que tiveram esses erros (No caso é uma empresa de suporte).

Preciso que o PHP faça o insert das Foreign Key de Clientes e/ou Funcionários, para que ele possa ser puxado pela view, que será exibida na página de consulta. Em relação ao banco está montado corretamente, mas não sei como puxar esses dados (as FK) no PHP.

Segue o código:

Script do Banco:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydb;

USE mydb;

CREATE TABLE clientes (
  cod_clientes INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome_cliente VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  cnpj VARCHAR (14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cod_clientes)
) ENGINE = innodb;

CREATE TABLE funcionarios (
  cod_funcionarios INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  login VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  senha VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  cpf VARCHAR (11) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (cod_funcionarios)
  ) ENGINE = innodb;

CREATE TABLE erros(
  cod_erros INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tipo_erro VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
  solucao TEXT NOT NULL,
  data_ocorrencia DATE,
  sistema VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  Fk_Funcionarios INT UNSIGNED,
  Fk_Clientes INT UNSIGNED,
  PRIMARY KEY (cod_erros),
  FOREIGN KEY (Fk_Funcionarios) REFERENCES funcionarios (cod_funcionarios) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  FOREIGN KEY (Fk_Clientes) REFERENCES clientes (cod_clientes) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
  ) ENGINE = innodb;
```

Script de Insert:

```
    USE mydb;

insert into clientes (nome_cliente, cnpj) values 
("maria", "99999999999998"),
("joao","99999999999997");
SELECT *FROM clientes;

insert into erros (tipo_erro, solucao, data_ocorrencia, sistema, Fk_Funcionarios, Fk_Clientes) values 
("Erro na Instancia ", "1) Verificar se o NET Framework 4.6.2 está instalado na máquina e com seus recursos ativados. (Verifique os recursos indo em -> Painel de Controle > Programas e Recursos > Ativar ou Desativar Recursos do Windows > Em todos Net framework que estão lá - ative todos os recursos e reinicie a máquina).  
2) Verificar se o IPV6 está desativado para evitar problemas de conexão.
3) Verificar se as regras de entrada no firewall estão habilitadas  em 'propriedades do Windows defender firewall', e habilitar as portas para evitar problemas (1433, 9004, 9009), e habilitar as regras de entrada também. Ou desativar o firewall (não recomendado).
4) Verificar se o Anti-vírus está atrapalhando com a conexão do Hiper.
5) Verificar em serviços (Win+R e digite: 'services.msc' ou vá em pesquisar no menu iniciar e digite: 'serviços'.), e verifique se as instâncias como o: SQL SERVER (Hiper) está ‘iniciado’.
6) Verificar  se o nome do 'desktop' e o do computador(logon / apelido da máquina) são iguais, pois se for, o SQL Server não irá aceitar fazer a conexão. Os nomes devem ser diferentes.
7) Agora abra o SSMS normalmente e faça o login com o SA sem por a senha, e depois configure.", "1888/08/25","HIPER", 1, 1),

("Falha de comunicação com o gestão", "Este erro é comum no Windows 7, devido as atualizações do Windows Update. Geralmente a atualização do Windows 7 não é automática como o do Windows 10. Então é necessário que faça a atualização do Windows Update.", "1888/08/25","HIPER",1, 2);
SELECT *FROM erros;
```

View:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS VIEW_LISTA_ERROS;

CREATE VIEW VIEW_LISTA_ERROS AS
SELECT clientes.nome_cliente AS Cliente, erros.cod_erros AS ID, erros.tipo_erro AS Erro, erros.solucao AS Solução, erros.data_ocorrencia AS Data, erros.sistema AS Sistema, funcionarios.email AS Email_do_Funcionario
FROM clientes, erros, funcionarios
where erros.Fk_Clientes = clientes.cod_clientes and erros.Fk_Funcionarios = funcionarios.cod_funcionarios
group by cod_erros, Fk_Clientes, Fk_Funcionarios;

select *from VIEW_LISTA_ERROS;
```

Parte do código do php onde estou tentando fazer o Insert (OBS: Sem as Foreign Key ele insere no banco, mas não adianta eu inserir sem as FK, porque se não a view não irá puxar e não terei o controle):

```
  //Caso não ocorra nenhum erro, permita que os dados sejam inseridos no banco.
  if ($row == 0) {

    $query2 = "insert into clientes(nome_cliente, cnpj)
    values('{$nome_cliente}', '{$cnpj}')";
    mysqli_query(conexao(), $query2);

    $query = "insert into erros(tipo_erro,solucao,data_ocorrencia,sistema)
    values('{$nome_erro}', ('{$solucao}'), ('{$data}'), '{$sistema}')";
    mysqli_query(conexao(), $query);
  }

  header('location: paginaConsulta.php');
}
```

Print do Formulário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Print da Pág de consulta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pra resumir sua pergunta: você quer saber como inserir os ids de cliente e funcionário nas chaves estrangeiras que irão para a tabela de erros?

Comment: @adrianosmateus Isso! Por exemplo: eu quero ter registro do funcionário que fez o cadastro dos erros e clientes, e também qual erro o cliente teve. No caso irei precisar das duas Foreign Key (ou chave primária, não sei como implementar)

Comment: Alguém pode me dar um help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito sua dúvida, é só jogar o id pra ser gravado na chave estrangeira dentro da query:

```
//Caso não ocorra nenhum erro, permita que os dados sejam inseridos no banco.
if ($row == 0) {
$conexao = conexao();

$query2 = "insert into clientes(nome_cliente, cnpj)
values('{$nome_cliente}', '{$cnpj}')";
mysqli_query($conexao, $query2);

//Recupero o id do cliente que acabou de ser inserido
$idCliente = mysqli_insert_id($conexao)

$query = "insert into erros(tipo_erro,solucao,data_ocorrencia,sistema, Fk_Funcionarios, Fk_Clientes)
values('{$nome_erro}', ('{$solucao}'), ('{$data}'), '{$sistema}', '{$idFuncionario}', '{$idCliente}')";
mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
}

header('location: paginaConsulta.php');
}
```

Declare a variável `$idFuncionario` e jogue nela o id do usuário que estiver ativo na sessão.

Comment: A parte de pegar o FK de clientes funcionou, mas eu não consigo pegar o  ID do usuário logado na sessão de jeito nenhum. Já tentei de várias formas mas nada da certo :/ Como eu pego o id do usuário logado na sessão, pode me dar uma dica?? Só falta isso pra terminar

Comment: Quando o usuário efetuar o login, grave o id dele na sessão, depois é só recuperar o id na hora de fazer o insert, por exemplo, fazendo session_start(); $idFuncionario = $_SESSION['id'];

Comment: Na pagina de login, joguei dentro da variável o resultado de td q tenho na tabela e dps joguei na sessão puxando o ID da tabela. Ai na pagina onde faço a inserção de dados, eu joguei essa sessão que puxa o id, na variavel $IDFuncionario. $dados_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $dados_usuario['cod_funcionarios']; OBRIGADO PELA FORÇA!

Comment: Por nada. Marca a resposta como correta se resolveu o seu problema.